# **kwargs key:value error with Swagger Python script

Tags: python, swagger

I am trying to generate a Python script using a Swagger generated client, and am getting the following error:

"The extended metadata filter 'extended' is invalid.  It should be of the format key:value"

from this line of code:

```
`response = mediaApi.media_query(**{'extended_filter':{'extended':'3'}})`
```

This is based on a line in the Swagger client as follows:

```
`#param list[str] extended_filter: A special filter which is of the form  'extendedFilter=Name;Value' which allows you to filter by extended metadata`
```

This line in the client also applies:

```
`if 'extended_filter' in params:
        query_params.append(('extendedFilter', params['extended_filter']))
        collection_formats['extendedFilter'] = 'multi'`
```

but I'm not clear on how to create the proper expression from this. Insights appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Got it--it was just this:

```
`response = mediaApi.media_query(**{'query':'query'})`
```